# How to coloriate differently even rows and odd rows of a List in LWUIT?

Tags: lwuit

There is a `List` in a LWUIT application. I want to make `odd rows` and `even rows` to be of different `colors`. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Have you checked the implementation of `ColorRenderer` in **LWUITDemo** project ? Try [this](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show/LWUIT_1_5/Apps/LWUITDemo?rev=1644) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set two differents UIIDs to the rows. Setting this UIID you can modify selectively the  colors of your rows.

**EDIT**

Ok this will be more difficult.

You need to make a `Render` and set it in your `List` with `List.setRender(Render r)`. 
The ´Render´ class will extend from `ListCellRender`. In this class you can set UIID to the `Render`, setting its Selected or Unselected styles.

See this example. @Shai Almog could have more info for your problem.

http://www.lwuit.com/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html

Comment: The problem is that the color is effect only when the row is selected when scrolling the list element. So how to effect the color for every rows ?

Comment: @pheromix To address this concern i have specifically left a comment to your question. Have you checked it ? source code [link](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/content/LWUIT_1_5/Apps/LWUITDemo/src/com/sun/lwuit/uidemo/RenderingDemo.java?rev=1644)

Comment: Keep in mind that the list renderer returns a Focus component which is the element you see animating when moving selection with the keys. It has a style of its own. When creating a renderer in the GUI builder you can select "pinstipe" renderer as an option which will automatically use styles ending with the words Odd/Even (read the docs next to the renderer entry) which allows a pinstripe effect. I think I demoed it in a video somewhere but I can't find it anymore. Need to redo the videos anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the Generic List Cell Renderer, you will probably have to create the styles in code, or set the UIID from the resource editor.

```
List list = new List(createGenericListCellRendererModelData());
list.setRenderer(new GenericListCellRenderer(createGenericRendererContainer(), createGenericRendererContainer()));


private Container createGenericRendererContainer() {
    Container c = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    c.setUIID("ListRenderer");
    Label name = new Label();
    name.setFocusable(true);
    name.setName("Name");
    c.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, name);
    Label surname = new Label();
    surname.setFocusable(true);
    surname.setName("Surname");
    c.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, surname);
    CheckBox selected = new CheckBox();
    selected.setName("Selected");
    selected.setFocusable(true);
    c.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, selected);
    return c;
}

private Hashtable[] createGenericListCellRendererModelData() {
    Hashtable[] data = new Hashtable[5];
    data[0] = new Hashtable();
    data[0].put("Name", "Shai");
    data[0].put("Surname", "Almog");
    data[0].put("Selected", Boolean.TRUE);
    data[1] = new Hashtable();
    data[1].put("Name", "Chen");
    data[1].put("Surname", "Fishbein");
    data[1].put("Selected", Boolean.TRUE);
    data[2] = new Hashtable();
    data[2].put("Name", "Ofir");
    data[2].put("Surname", "Leitner");
    data[3] = new Hashtable();
    data[3].put("Name", "Yaniv");
    data[3].put("Surname", "Vakarat");
    data[4] = new Hashtable();
    data[4].put("Name", "Meirav");
    data[4].put("Surname", "Nachmanovitch");
    return data;
}
```

Full details here : http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2011/03/list-rendering-easy-way-generic-list.html (code gotten from this link).